# instance of class C#

Tags: c#, struct, instance

I am pretty new to C# programming so sorry for dumb questions.

I set up `DeviceInfos` class, which I like to use every loop. So at the end I like to have so many "the same" classes, how many is "nod"´s.

I nicely defined new Instance of my `DeviceInfos` class, but without "indexing support" :) How to fix this?

My public class DeviceInfos:

```
public class DeviceInfos
{
    public bool boolSerialNumber;
    public byte[] byteSerialNumber;
    public string stringSerialNumber;
    public bool boolManufacturer;
    public byte[] byteManufacturer;
    public string stringManufacturer;
    public bool boolProduct;
    public byte[] byteProduct;
    public string stringProduct;
    public HidDeviceData.ReadStatus ReadStatus { get; set; }
    public bool boolWriteNameSuccess;
    public bool boolReadNameSuccess;
    public string stringName;
```

And code where comes to error:

```
DeviceInfos _deviceInfo = new DeviceInfos();
for (nod = 0; nod < _deviceList.Length; nod++)
{
    _deviceInfo[nod].boolSomething= false;
    _deviceInfo[nod].boolSomething = _deviceList[nod].ReadSerialNumber(out    _deviceInfo[nod].byteSerialNumber);

...
```

Error Acoour: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in USBmiddlewareDeveloping.exe

This happend in row

```
_deviceInfo[nod].boolSerialNumber = false;
```

Why? Or how to do it?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is, but you should not be changing the values of structs (they should be immutable).  If you need to change the property values use a `class` instead.  Why are using a struct anyways?

Comment: No clear buddy on what you want...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need help with. Also use class instead of structs.

Comment: DO you mean that you want to define a List<DeviceInfos> instead??

Comment: I change to class and update the post. If helps anything. Want I want is just use instance of my Class. But allways come an error "System.NullReferenceException"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to declare an array of your structs:

```
DeviceInfos[] _deviceInfos = new DeviceInfos[_deviceList.Length];
for (nod = 0; nod < _deviceList.Length; nod++)
{
    _deviceInfos[nod] = new DeviceInfos();
    _deviceInfo[nod].boolSomething= false;
    ...
```

And consider renaming your struct to `DeviceInfo` if it only represents a single device. Also, as already commented, consider making it a class, not a struct.

Answer (score 0):

As D Stanley suggested, a class is likely what you need. There are several enumerable classes built-in to the language, such as List< T >() (T is the generic denotation for an object, such as a DeviceInfo class). List is my personal favorite; I prefer lists for their LINQ functions and the ability to add and remove objects easily. You could have:

```
var deviceInfos = new List<DeviceInfo>();
for(var nod = 0; nod < deviceInfos.Count; nod++)
{
    var deviceInfo = deviceInfos[nod];
    byte[] byteSerialNumber;
    deviceInfo.boolSomething = deviceInfo.ReadSerialNumber(out byteSerialNumber);
    deviceInfo.byteSerialNumber = byteSerialNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quesition is vague one; in case you want to create an array from list
you can use *Linq*:

```
DeviceInfo[] _deviceInfo = _deviceList // <- source
  .Select(item => new DeviceInfo() {   // <- data representation
       boolSomething = false,
       someOther = item.someOtherData,
       ...
     })
  .ToArray();                          // <- finally to array
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need indexing support for your struct, check this out:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx

In your struct, something like:

```
        public YourType this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return yourList[index];
            }

            set
            {
                yourList[index] = value;
            }
        }
```